# How to open facebook.com/recover from the mobile app?

Tags: facebook, account-recovery

Someone forgot his Facebook password, he got logged out but is still logged into Facebook messenger. He wants to login again.

He has 2 methods of recovery:

- Send password to email, and he can't do that because he linked his Facebook account to an old Hotmail account which he no longer remembers.
- He has 3 trusted contacts, he should ask them to visit https://www.facebook.com/recover and give him the code.

The 3 contacts are his mom, dad and sister. All 3 forgot their passwords so they can login only from mobile. They are not able to access the link from a browser while logged in.

They should go to https://www.facebook.com/recover and give him the code for him to login. How to do that on mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it after asking the question immediately:

- Ask your contact to send a message to someone in Facebook messenger containing the link https://www.facebook.com/recover, with `https://`, so it should be a link, or he can write the link on his timeline, the link should be written somewhere inside the app or the messenger
- Then ask your contact to click on it, only then, the link will open within Facebook, and you can get the code.

  If there's an easier way to do it let me know, I'll upvote and accept your answer.