# Is it possible to contact Facebook asking them to recover an account?

Tags: facebook, account-recovery

If someone can't recover his Facebook account by any mean. Is it possible to send his ID to Facebook and ask them to recover his account?

Because earlier this year I filled a form asking Facebook to recover an account which was hacked and the profile changed, so Facebook recovered it for him, I forgot what the form was and I don't know if they do that if no one is being impersonated, or if the account is not disabled.

Comment: I closed this question because it doesn't meet the [current quality standards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error). Related: [Should I vote to close old questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194116/289691) , [As a mod when should I vote to close content that is not flagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124097/289691)

Comment: Related: [How to open facebook.com/recover from the mobile app?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/120923/88163)

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect your account was hacked, you can get immediate help by reporting the account here: [Report compromised account](https://www.facebook.com/hacked).

For more information check the Facebook Help Center -> [Hacked Accounts](https://www.facebook.com/help/131719720300233?ref=u2u)

Answer (score 1):

None of the links above let me contact them directly, today I found [this form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/357439354283890) and contacted them, not sure if they will reply, but that's a different issue.